# Do I have to explicitly create Persistent Volume when I am using Persistent Volume Claim?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am new to Kubernetes, and I struggle to understand whol idea behind Persistent Storage in Kubernetes.

So is this enough or I have to create Persistent Volume and what will happen if I deploy only these two object without creating PV?

Storage should be on local machine.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: nginx-logs
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-web
  name: app-web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-web
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-web
    spec:
      containers:
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: app-web
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/log/nginx
          name: nginx-logs
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-logs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in [the doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) that it mentions a Dynamic way of provisioning persistent volumes.

> When none of the static PVs the administrator created match a user's
> PersistentVolumeClaim, the cluster may try to dynamically provision a
> volume specially for the PVC. This provisioning is based on
> StorageClasses: the PVC must request a storage class and the
> administrator must have created and configured that class for dynamic
> provisioning to occur. Claims that request the class "" effectively
> disable dynamic provisioning for themselves.

When I apply your pvc, it creates a gp2 volume because that is my default storage class.

```
$kubectl get pvc
NAME         STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nginx-logs   Bound    pvc-b95a9d0c-ef46-4ff0-a034-d2dde1ac1f96   1Gi        RWO            gp2            6s
```

You can see your default storage class like this

```
$kubectl get storageclass
NAME            PROVISIONER                                           AGE
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs                                 355d
```

You can also include a specific storage class.  You can read more about that [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/).

> Users request dynamically provisioned storage by including a storage
> class in their PersistentVolumeClaim

In short, your current pvc file will use your default storage class to create a Persistent Volume and then you are mounting that volume into your pod via your Persistent Volume Claim in your Deployment.

Comment: Ah I see, this is a really good explanation! And my default StorageClass is local-path which was what I want to achieve

Answer (score 4):

> I struggle to understand whole idea behind Persistent Storage in Kubernetes

The idea is to separate the *storage request* that the app needs, and the physical storage - such that an app can be moved to e.g. other cloud provider that has a different storage system - but without needing any changes in the app. It also separates the responsibility for "requesting storage" and managing the underlying storage e.g. developers vs operations.

> So is this enough or I have to create Persistent Volume and what will happen if I deploy only these two object without creating PV?

This depends on you environment. Most environments typically have [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/), e.g. the big cloud providers and now also Minikube has support for this.

When using dynamic volume provisioning, the developer only has to create a `PersistentVolumeClaim` - and no `PersistentVolume`, its instead dynamically provsioned.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful! And seems like my environment has Dynamic Volume Provisioning, because I didn't get any error as @Argha said that should happen. I am using K3s distribution of Kubernetes. 

But would you consider this as a good practice or you would still explicitly create PV?

Comment: yes, I would always try to use Dynamic Volume Provisioning if that fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 3):

A PV which matches with the PVC in terms of `capacity(100Mi)` and `accessModes(ReadWriteOnce)`is needed.If you don't have a PV you get error `pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`. So either you create the PV manually(called static provisioning) or rely on storage class and volume driver to do it automatically(called dynamic provisioning).

A PV is a kubernetes representation of volume. The actual volume still need to be provisioned.If you use [dynamic volume provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) and your cloud provider has a volume driver the provisioning is automated internally by the driver without needing to create a PV manually.

In a local non cloud system you can use [local path provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner) to use dynamic provisioning. Configure a default [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) and you can avoid manual PV creation.

Comment: hmm after all these answers seems like my distribution of kubernetes - k3s has default storageclass and that is local-path, that is why this was working for me without creating PV or StorageClass

Comment: Yeah rancher has https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner